# How to carry out R nested looping by index with three vectors

Tags: r, nested-loops, intersect

I am trying to carry out the intersect of the 3 vectors. I intend the x, y ,z to take up values as intended below and be inserted to the `trans.list`, `prot.list` and `PT.list`.

```r
#v = number of vectors (number of sets)
V <- 3
#N= number of clusters in each set
N <- 5
intersects <- vector(length=N^V,mode='character')

for (x in 1:N) {
 for (y in 1:N) {
   for (z in 1:N) {
     inters <- length(Reduce(intersect, 
       list(
            trans.list[[x]][["NAME"]],
            prot.list[[y]][["NAME"]],
            PT.list[[z]][["NAME"]]
           )
     ))
     
intersects[x, y, z] <- inters
```

However at the end, I cant seem to save it to index as a value. any advice?

```
[1] "1,1,1"
[1] "1,1,2"
[1] "1,1,3"
[1] "1,1,4"
[1] "1,1,5"
[1] "1,2,1"
[1] "1,2,2"
...
```

Comment: `expand.grid(1:N, 1:N, 1:N)`

Comment: `expand.grid(rep(list(seq(N)), v))`

Comment: @Onyambu where do you think I should insert that?

Comment: Your whole code can be given with what i wrote.